# Determine if these two norms are equivalent

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Let we have the space $C[a,b]$ (the space of all functions that are continuous on closed interval $[a,b]$). And we have two norms on this space:

$$\|X\|_1= \max_{t\in [a,b]} | x(t) |$$
$$\|X\|_2 = \left( \int_a^b | x(t) |^2 dt \right)^{1/2}$$

Are these norms on this space equivalent or not equivalent and why ?

Comment: By the way, don't feel discouraged by down-votes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me do it in $[0,1]$. Any interval is the same.

Notice that $f_n(x)=0$ for $1\geq x>1/n$ and $f_n(x)=-nx+1$ for $x\in[0,1/n]$ is Cauchy in $||\cdot||_2$ but not in $||\cdot||_1$

We can check it by computing a bit. Let $0$ be the zero function when appropriate.

$$||f_n-0||_1=||f_n||_1=max |f| = 1$$

while

$$||f_n-0||_2=||f_n||_2=\left(\int_{0}^{1/n}\left|nx-1\right|^2\right)^{1/2}=\left(\frac{1}{3n^2}\right)^{1/2}\to 0$$

Comment: +1 Welcome to the site and good answer! To make your answer more complete you could specify that if two norms are equivalent, then every sequence that is cauchy in one norm will also be cauchy in the other. :)

Comment: @user192614 how can I prove that

Comment: @user192614 can you show me why this sequence in this second norm is Cauchy  and  in the other is not Cauchy

Comment: @MhmdSyria Done.

Comment: @user192614 thanks you so much

Comment: @MhmdSyria what I wrote is wrong. Let me fix it.

Comment: @MhmdSyria Done. I had evaluated from $1/n$ to $1$ instead of from $0$ to $1/n$.

Comment: @user192614 but this function is not continuos Becaxuse when X strive to 1/n from below equals -1/n*2+1 but when X strive to 1/n from above equals zero

Comment: @MhmdSyria Oh, put the $n$ in the numerator. The idea is just to have a triangle of constant height but such that the basis shrinks.

Comment: @user192614 you mean these norms are not equivalent because the same sequence has different end by each of them 
Its limit in the first norm is one and in the other is zero